# `from..where` or `FirstOrDefault` in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Traditionally, when I've tried to get data for a user from a database, and I've used the following method (to some degree):

```
DbUsers curUser = context.DbUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.u_LoginName == id);
string name = curUser.u_Name;
string email = curUser.u_Email;
```

You can see that all I want to do is get the Name and Email, but it seems to me that this LINQ query is getting **everything** stored in the database of that user, bringing it back, then allowing me to get what I want.

I have been doing some research and have found the following alternative:

```
var current = from s in context.DbUsers
where s.u_LoginName == id
select new {
             name = s.u_Name, 
             email = s.u_Email
           };
foreach (var user in current)
{
    //Stuff Here
}
```

Which would be better, if any at all? Is there a lighter method to use when I only want to retrieve a few results / data?

Comment: The second is the way to go if you do not want ALL the data collected, but just a few fields. Fire up a SQL server profiler and check the difference in the querries

Comment: Second one when you need lesser data (selected data).

Comment: And don't forget to throw a little `Any()` security check before doing anything ^^

Comment: i've seen people sprinkle "any" queries before every actual query to make sure that they will be getting a result ... this is a terrible idea, it creates unnecessary round-trips to the database ... "FirstOrDefault()" handles the no-data case perfectly well in one round-trip to the database

Comment: @TCC So you'd use `FirstOrDefault` over `SingleOrDefault`?

Comment: @NewAmbition, SingleOrDefault throws an exception if there is more than one result.  It determines this by querying the top 2 results and throwing an exception if two are actually retrieved.  If one is retrieved, it is returned.  If none are retrieved, the object default is returned.

Comment: I use both when appropriate. In this case without knowing all of the details I think I would use `SingleOrDefault`. There is a third option , `Take(2)`, which I sometimes use. `SingleOrDefault` lets you know if the query would return exactly one record or not, when the method returns default you are left to wonder "so were there 0, or more than 1 records". If the database has a unique constraint, then you know the answer must be 0. Otherwise `Take(2)` is an efficient way to determine if a query matches 0, 1, or more than 1 records (this is what `SingleOrDefault` does behind the scenes anyway).

Comment: Would `Take(2)` not result in more bandwidth / processing time?

Comment: @Ethenyl there's no _security_ in that. The code will blow up if it's not there (and none are found). But then again you might have meant robustness

Comment: I'm assuming that if the query returns two or more users that would constitute an error. If that's correct you might want to consider `SingleOrDefault` instead. THis will enforce that. Yes you'd then need to handle an exception but since it is then an exceptional case that's a good thing. If the assumption is correct you are hidding an error instead of handling the error, not so good and makes for loong debuggin nights when the bug surfaces

Comment: Hrm I have to correct my previous comment... `SingleOrDefault` throws if there are more than one result. My larger point remains that there are clear times when FirstOrDefault, SingleOrDefault and something like Take(2) will get you what you want, and any of these is one round trip to the database, and is far better than calling `.Any()` before executing your query and getting results. If you are unclear when to use each of these, do a lot of testing until you understand their behavior. not to be rude but this is fundamental behavior you really must understand, so test until you understand :)

Comment: @RuneFS to add to your point, `SingleOrDefault` is especially the way to go if there is a database unique constraint guaranteeing only one user would be returned. In that case you might not even put a local exception handler, but let it bubble up, as it would represent a database failure (really bad) and surely your app isn't designed to work well in the case that all of your unique constraints are failing to function properly :) ... at least I don't protect against those types of errors myself, maybe i should

Answer (score 68, accepted):

If you want to get only two fields, then you should project your entity *before* query gets executed (and in this case query gets executed when you call `FirstOrDefault`). Use `Select` operator for projection to anonymous object with required fields:

```
var user = context.DbUsers
                  .Where(u => u.u_LoginName == id)
                  .Select(u => new { u.u_Name, u.u_Email })
                  .FirstOrDefault(); // query is executed here

string name = user.u_Name; // user is anonymous object
string email = user.u_Email;
```

That will generate SQL like:

```
 SELECT TOP 1 u_Name, u_Email FROM DbUsers
 WHERE u_LoginName = @id
```

In second case you are doing projection *before* query gets executed (i.e. enumeration started). That's why only required fields are loaded. But query will be slightly different (without `TOP 1`). Actually if you will convert second approach to lambda syntax, it will be almost same:

```
var query = context.DbUsers
                   .Where(u => u.u_LoginName == id)
                   .Select(u => new { u.u_Name, u.u_Email }); 

// query is defined but not executed yet
foreach (var user in query) // executed now
{
   //Stuff Here
}
```

And just to show complete picture, without projection you get all fields of first found user:

```
DbUsers user = context.DbUsers
                      .Where(u => u.u_LoginName == id)
                      .FirstOrDefault(); // query is executed here

string name = user.u_Name; // user is DbUsers entity with all fields mapped
string email = user.u_Email;
```

In that case user entity is not projected before query is executed and you'll get all fields of user loaded from database and mapped to user entity:

```
 SELECT TOP 1 u_LoginName, u_Name, u_Email /* etc */ FROM DbUsers
 WHERE u_LoginName = @id
```

Comment: It all of a sudden seems so obvious.

Comment: _"If you want to get only two fields, then you should project your entity before query gets executed "_ Does it really matter if i select two properties of an anonymous type or a fully initialized object? The latter has the advantage that i can use it everywhere where i need `DbUsers` objects. A table should not contain hundred columns anyway. Also, you're normally not selecting millions of users but few (or only one).

Comment: It also worth mentioning that you can project the data into a separate type aswell. It does not have to be a anonymous type => `new MyType { Username = u.u_Name }`

Comment: @TimSchmelter I agree that usually you just select whole object and does not think which fields you need. But sometimes you should work with legacy database, or denormalized tables (ouch!) and loading of hundred columns becomes real problem.

Comment: @scheien: You could, but this has the disadvantage that you have half-initialized objects which could cause problems somewhere.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Sure, if you do not account for that situation :)

Comment: @scheien: Maybe you or your fellows trust that database objects follow the same rules as in the database. So if you have a non-nullable column somebody could think that the property can also never be null.

Comment: Enumerate all columns that you need, and select just them from database (for sake of standardization of code, explicit field, etc..) Why would you bring info from database, consuming **bandwidth**, which you won't need?

Comment: In the sql-like syntax, you can still get the single-result as well, by combining with the extension methods: `(from s in ... select new {...}).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: @BrianS I honestly did not know you could do that! Thanks!

Comment: @TimSchmelter you can use an object of an anonymous time anywhere you like with in the same assembly too. Yes you need and extention method for the cast to accomplish that ` T Cast<T>(T pattern, object obj){ return (T)obj;}` If you provide an anonymously typed object with the same structure as the projection then it'll work just like a cast to a named type. However since anonymous types have assmebly scope this is internal only

Answer (score 11):

The second is better. You only get the needed data from database so the network traffic is lighter.

You can have the same result with extension methods:

```
var user = context.DbUsers
                  .Where(x => x.u_LoginName == id)
                  .Select(x => new {...})
                  .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need not whole entity, but some values from it, then use `new {name = s.u_Name, email = s.u_Email}`. Because, this object is much "lighter" for cunstruction.
When you get entity with FirstOrDefault, it' saved in DBContext, but you don't do anything with it.
So, i advice you to get only data you need.